# Use CASE in WHERE clause - Data Parameters Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to verify the example, if the date is null pick a date from another field. Below the query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OrderPublish OP
    INNER JOIN Advertising AD ON
        AD.IdOrderPublish = OP.IdOrderPublish
    INNER JOIN Client Cli ON
        Cli.IdClient = OP.IdClient
    LEFT JOIN AdvertisingInserted AII ON
        AD.IdAdvertisingInserted = AII.IdAdvertisingInserted
    LEFT JOIN TypeProduct TP ON
        AII.IdTypeProduct = TP.IdTypeProduct
    INNER JOIN Publication PUB ON
        PUB.IdAdvertisingInserted = AII.IdAdvertisingInserted
WHERE
    TP.IdTypeProduct in (5,7)
    AND CASE WHEN PUB.DtIni IS NULL
        THEN
            OP.DtInc >= Isnull('08/18/2013', OP.DtInc)
        ELSE
            PUB.DtIni >= Isnull('08/18/2013', PUB.DtIni)
        END
    AND CASE PUB.DtFinal WHEN NULL
        THEN
            OP.DtInc <= Isnull('08/23/2013', OP.DtInc)
        ELSE
            PUB.DtFinal <= Isnull('08/23/2013', PUB.DtFinal)
        END
```

Comment: Dear, if AII is null (LEFT OUTER JOIN fails) when you use INNER JOIN on the same AII table, you lose your rows. Are you sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `COALESCE()` in your case, but if you want to use `CASE` in `WHERE` criteria you can do so. Move the matching criteria outside the `CASE` statement, you need the `CASE` statement to return the values to be compared, not the comparison itself. This requires doubling up each `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OrderPublish OP
    INNER JOIN Advertising AD ON
        AD.IdOrderPublish = OP.IdOrderPublish
    INNER JOIN Client Cli ON
        Cli.IdClient = OP.IdClient
    LEFT JOIN AdvertisingInserted AII ON
        AD.IdAdvertisingInserted = AII.IdAdvertisingInserted
    LEFT JOIN TypeProduct TP ON
        AII.IdTypeProduct = TP.IdTypeProduct
    INNER JOIN Publication PUB ON
        PUB.IdAdvertisingInserted = AII.IdAdvertisingInserted
WHERE
    TP.IdTypeProduct in (5,7)
    AND CASE WHEN PUB.DtIni IS NULL
        THEN
            OP.DtInc
        ELSE
            PUB.DtIni 
        END
    >=  CASE WHEN PUB.DtIni IS NULL
        THEN
            Isnull('08/18/2013', OP.DtInc)
        ELSE
            Isnull('08/18/2013', PUB.DtIni)
        END

    AND CASE PUB.DtFinal WHEN NULL
        THEN
            OP.DtInc 
        ELSE
            PUB.DtFinal 
        END
    <= CASE PUB.DtFinal WHEN NULL
        THEN
            Isnull('08/23/2013', OP.DtInc)
        ELSE
            Isnull('08/23/2013', PUB.DtFinal)
        END
```

That's how you can use a `CASE` statement in your `WHERE` criteria, but you could use `AND ()` and `OR ()` criteria along with `COALESCE()` to do this without the `CASE`

Also, Your `ISNULL()` statements are backwards, `'08/18/2013'` will never be `NULL`, so the field won't be evaluated, you probably mean:  `Isnull(OP.DtInc,'08/23/2013')`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of case you can try Coalesce function :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OrderPublish OP
    INNER JOIN Advertising AD ON
        AD.IdOrderPublish = OP.IdOrderPublish
    INNER JOIN Client Cli ON
        Cli.IdClient = OP.IdClient
    LEFT JOIN AdvertisingInserted AII ON
        AD.IdAdvertisingInserted = AII.IdAdvertisingInserted
    LEFT JOIN TypeProduct TP ON
        AII.IdTypeProduct = TP.IdTypeProduct
    INNER JOIN Publication PUB ON
        PUB.IdAdvertisingInserted = AII.IdAdvertisingInserted
WHERE
    TP.IdTypeProduct in (5,7)
    AND Coalesce(PUB.DtIni,OP.DtInc)>= Isnull('08/18/2013', OP.DtInc)
    AND Coalesce(PUB.DtFinal,OP.DtInc)<= Isnull('08/23/2013', OP.DtInc)
```